# Search orders by customer email OR name

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I modify `wc_get_orders` so that the parameters passed are “OR” instead of “AND”? Say I want to find orders that match ANY of the parameters provided, not ALL.

Like this example: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#address-and-name – I’d like to fetch orders where firstname is Claudio OR lastname is Sanches

Comment: There is always [wordpress.se] to search/post in too.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/337722

Comment: Upon my own research prior to asking this question, naturally, I took myself and the community the courtesy of searching a bit around first. I also stumbled upon this question, and it's close, but not exactly what I am asking. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you try anything to modify the technique to suot your goal? My first comment is now erased, so I'll ask again... Can you just query for first, query for last, then merge the results?

Comment: @mickmackusa perhaps my own question should be rephrased. Let's say I'd like to query WooCommerce orders by either Order ID or Order Date. I'm doing a broad search engine to find results based on whatever the user is typing, and therefore "OR" instead of "AND" queries work better

Comment: @mickmackusa in WP_Query you have the `'meta_query' => ['relation' => 'OR']` property, and ideally I'm looking for something equivalent for wc_order_query

Comment: I understand your requirement, but I do not WP so I'm bowing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'rmg_woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query' );
function rmg_woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query( $wp_query_args ) {

    if (is_array($wp_query_args['meta_query'])) {
        $wp_query_args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'OR';
    }
    return $wp_query_args;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Reigel - that looks correct. However, how can I do it for the main fields? Say `billing_first_name` and `billing_last_name`

Comment: it looks like billing_last_name is already meta, so I guess your answer fixes this